# Regex - return time stamp from last job run (CSV file)

Tags: regex, vb.net, csv

```
[00/00/0000 00:00:00]     EVENT: event    STATUS: success      JOB: jobnameA     MACHINE: machine
[00/00/0000 00:00:00]     EVENT: event    STATUS: failed       JOB: jobnameB     MACHINE: machine
[11/11/1111 11:11:11]     EVENT: event    STATUS: success      JOB: jobnameA     MACHINE: machine
[12/12/1212 12:12:12]     EVENT: event    STATUS: success      JOB: jobnameB     MACHINE: machine
[22/22/2222 22:22:22]     EVENT: event    STATUS: hold         JOB: jobnameC     MACHINE: machine
```

These are two sample line from a .csv log file showing wo differen job runs.  I'm trying to use regex to return the timestamp (\[.{19}\]) from the last run of the matching jobname.

Using VB.NET:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\[.{19}\](?=.+?status         JOB: jobname)"

reader = New StreamReader(path)
fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd()
m = Regex.Match(fileContents, pattern)
```

My current pattern returns the first match instead of the last, but even if I do get the right expression, this feels horribly cumbersome and also like the wrong approach.

So first off, how can I make this give me the last run of jobname and also, how can I do this more efficiently?

EDIT:  I'm looking for the timestamp for the second (aka last) run of jobnameA

Comment: Is this all on one line? If you just want the time **`\[(.*)]`** that should get it between the `[ ]`...

Comment: For some reason or another Regex101.com is having some problems saving, I finally got the link. See **https://regex101.com/r/kP9dQ8/1** the implementation there... Also in your example pattern you need to enclose the whole thing in a capturing group, yours is not. Of course it will find the match, but there's no capturing groups... So it would become `(\[.{19}\](?=.+?status         JOB: jobname))`...

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  In your example, you have 4 lines, and the timestamp is matched on all 4 lines.  I'm looking to get just the last one.

Comment: Oh didn't understand that, I was thinking all matches :) Just a little modification then...

Comment: The pattern I posted returned the first timestamp already...it is this modification I seek :)

Comment: Sorry it took a bit, but how about **https://regex101.com/r/kP9dQ8/2** this version?

Comment: I feel terrible, sorry, I shoul'dve been more specific.  I've edited the original post.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's not how SO works, you can't keep changing the original question. I believe my answer solved your issue (original issue). If you keep changing your questions, no one will help you. Besides you changed it after my answer, so the solution given is not going to work...

Comment: I understand your frustration but my ask has never changed....I just provided better examples for you to visualize. From the very beginning I've always asked for "I'm trying to use regex to return the timestamp (\[.{19}\]) from the last run of the matching jobname."

If you test my original pattern, it returns the same thing your first answer did...hence I wouldn't have asked for that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...not sure if it's the best way, but it got me there.  You can put any status or jobname.

```
pattern = "\n\[(.*)].*(success.*jobnameA)(?!.*\2)"
```

or better yet to use variables

```
pattern = "\n\[(.*)].*(" & status & ".*" & jobname & ")(?!.*\2)"
```

Explanation:

**\n**  - matches a line-feed (newline) character
**[(.*)]**  - gives us the timestamp (capture group 1)
**.***  - matches any character any amount of times until specified job status
**status**  - is job status (can be anything is passed in by variable)
**.***  - any character any amount of times (space in this instance)
**jobname**  - is specified job (passed through a variable)
**(?!.*\2)**  - is a negative lookahead which uses the second capture group 
(status/jobname) to ensure it only returns the last entry of said job in the given status